# Put operands first in getopt()

Tags: c, linux, getopt

Using the `getopt()` function in C, it is possible to do that:

```
program -a arg_for_a -b arg_for_b -c operand1 operand2
```

and it works with no problem.

But, how to make it work this way?:

```
program operand1 operand2 -a arg_for_a -b arg_for_b -c
```

In this case, every argument, including the `-a`, `-b` etc. are considered to be operands.

I'm trying to make just like like `gcc` or `ssh` does:

```
gcc code.c -o executable
ssh user@host -i file.pem
```

That is, no matter in what position the options and the operands come, they are recognized properly.

How to make options be recognized properly wherever they are, and every word that do not follow an option be recognized an operand?

Comment: You can parse the arguments (those given to `main`) manually. `gcc` does that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the GNU C library's implementation of getopt, then it will work like all GNU utilities do, because almost all of them use it. In particular, (quoting from `man 3 getopt`):

> By default, getopt() permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.

That's not quite the same as `gcc`. `gcc` cares about the relative order of optional and positional arguments. (For example, it makes a difference where `-l` goes in the command line.) To do that, you'll have to tell GNU `getopt` to *not* permute the arguments. Then, every time `getopt` reports that it's done, `optind` will have the index of the next positional argument (if any). You can then use that argument, increment `optind`, and continue using `getopt`, which will continue at the next argument.

Comment: If you set the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, GNU `getopt()` will insist that options come before non-options, as God intended (OK; I mean 'as Dennis and Ken and crew intended', and 'as POSIX mandates').

Comment: Also, if you have GNU `getopt()`, you can place a `-` at the start of the option string.  It will then return non-option arguments as they are encountered, so you can process files and options in sequence.  The return from `getopt()` is 0 when a non-option argument is encountered.