# Mass arguments (operands) at first place in command line argument passing

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, getopts

I use following lines (hope this is best practice if not correct me please) to handle command line options:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -r -d '' HELP <<EOF
OPTIONS:
-c    Enable color output
-d    Enable debug output
-v    Enable verbose output
-n    Only download files (mutually exclusive with -r)
-r    Only remove files (mutually exclusive with -n)
-h    Display this help
EOF

# DECLARE VARIABLES WITH DEFAULT VALUES
color=0
debug=0
verbose=0
download=0
remove=0


OPTIND=1                # Reset in case getopts has been used previously in the shell
invalid_options=();     # Array for invalid options

while getopts ":cdvnrh" opt; do
  echo "Actual opt: $opt"
  case $opt in
    c)
      color=1
      ;;
    d)
      debug=1
      ;;
    v)
      verbose=1
      ;;
    n)
      download=1
      ;;
    r)
      remove=1
      ;;
    h)
      echo "$HELP"
      exit 1
      ;;
   \?)
      invalid_options+=($OPTARG)
      ;;
   *)
      invalid_options+=($OPTARG)
      ;;
  esac
done

# HANDLE INVALID OPTIONS
if [ ${#invalid_options[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Invalid option(s):" >&2
  for i in "${invalid_options[@]}"; do
    echo $i >&2
  done
  echo "" >&2
  echo "$HELP" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# SET $1 TO FIRST MASS ARGUMENT, $2 TO SECOND MASS ARGUMENT ETC
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

# HANDLE CORRECT NUMBER OF MASS OPTIONS
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Correct number of mass arguments are 2"
  echo "" >&2
  echo "$HELP" >&2
  exit 1
fi


# HANDLE MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE OPTIONS
if [ $download -eq 1 ] && [ $remove -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Options for download and remove are mutually exclusive" >&2
  echo "$HELP" >&2
  exit 1
fi



echo "color:    $color"
echo "debug:    $debug"
echo "verbose:  $verbose"
echo "download: $download"
echo "remove:   $remove"
echo "\$1:      $1"
echo "\$2:      $2"
```

If I call the script way that [mass arguments](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) (those that are not switches or arguments for switches) are last arguments everything is working correctly:

```
$ ./getopts.sh -c -d -v -r a b
Actual opt: c
Actual opt: d
Actual opt: v
Actual opt: r
color:    1
debug:    1
verbose:  1
download: 0
remove:   1
$1:      a
$2:      b
```

The problem is when I want to call the script so the mass arguments are first (or somewhere in the middle of switches that do not use arguments)

```
$ ./getopts.sh a b -c -d -v -r
Correct number of mass arguments are 2

OPTIONS:
-c    Enable color output
-d    Enable debug output
-v    Enable verbose output
-n    Only download files (mutually exclusive with -r)
-r    Only remove files (mutually exclusive with -d)
-h    Display this help
```

or

```
$ ./getopts.sh -c a b -d -v -r
Actual opt: c
Correct number of mass arguments are 2

OPTIONS:
-c    Enable color output
-d    Enable debug output
-v    Enable verbose output
-n    Only download files (mutually exclusive with -r)
-r    Only remove files (mutually exclusive with -d)
-h    Display this help
```

I think this should be OK according (POSIX) standards, because following syntax which is basically the same is working as expected on my system:

```
$ cp test1/ test2/ -r
$ cp test1/ -r test2/
```

I have search over the Internet but only thing that was close to my problem was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690289/put-operands-first-in-getopt) related to C.

Comment: Your observations are correct: getopts returns an exit status when the first non-option argument is encountered, so the while-loop ends. I believe [`getopt`](http://man.cx/getopt) can work in the more flexible way you want.

Comment: @glennjackman there are recommendations for using getopts over getopt. AFAIK getopt is considered obsolete.

Comment: I don't believe getopt is considered obsolete. getopts is easier to use (IMO: it's what I use) but it does force you to put the options before the required parameters and you cannot use --longoptions.

Comment: I just use a normal `case` statement and `shift` for the same yet more versatile effect.

Answer (score 4):

`getopts` automatically breaks the while loop as soon as it detects a non-dash parameter (not including the argument given to *dash* parameters that take arguments). The [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) standard is to have dashed parameters come first, and then have *files*. There's also none of this `--` and `+` crap either. It's plain and simple.

However, Linux isn't Unix or POSIX compliant. It's just in the nature of the GNU utilities to be "*better*" than the standard Unix utilities. More features, more options, and handling things a bit differently.

On Linux, command line parameters can come *after* files in many GNU utilities.

For example:

```
$ cp -R foo bar
```

Work on my Unix certified Mac OS X and on Linux, However,

```
$ cp foo bar -R
```

Only works on Linux.

If you want `getopts` to work like a lot of Linux utilities, you need to do a wee bit of work.

First, you have to process your arguments yourself, and not depend upon `$OPTIND` to parse them. You also need to verify that you have an argument.

I came up with this as an example of doing what you want.

```
#! /bin/bash

while [[ $* ]]
do
    OPTIND=1
    echo $1
    if [[ $1 =~ ^- ]]
    then
        getopts :a:b:cd parameter
        case $parameter in
            a)  echo "a"
                echo "the value is $OPTARG"
                shift
                ;;
            b)  echo "b"
                echo "the value is $OPTARG"
                shift
                ;;
            c)  echo "c"
                ;;
            d)  echo "d"
                ;;
            *) echo "This is an invalid argument: $parameter"
                ;;
        esac
    else
        other_arguments="$other_arguments $1"
    fi
    shift
done
echo "$other_arguments"
```

I now loop as long as `$*` is set. (Maybe I should use `$@`?) I have to do a `shift` at the end of the loop. I also reset `$OPTIND` to `1` each time because I'm shifting the arguments off myself. `$OPTARG` is still set, but I have to do another `shift` to make sure everything works.

I also have to verify if a argument begins with a dash or not using a regular expression in my `if` statement.

Basic testing shows it works, but I can't say it's error free, but it does give you an idea how you have to handle your program.

There's still plenty of power you're getting from `getopts`, but it does take a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

Bash provides two methods for argument parsing.

The built-in command `getopts` is a newer, easy to use mechanism how to parse arguments but it is not very flexible. `getopts` does not allow to mix options and mass arguments.

The external command `getopt` is an older and more complex mechanism to parse arguments. It allows long/short options and the gnu extension allow to mix options and mass arguments.